# Vertical Column headers in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have DataGrid as below

```
        Column1   COlumn2
Row1
Row2
```

My requirement is

```
          Row1     Row2
Column1
Column2
```

How is this possible with Silverlight Datagrid.

Comment: set DataGrid's style

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is an option like this in the DataGrid. Most likely you will have to transform your data prior to displaying it in the grid. See if the link below helps.

http://blogs.telerik.com/xamlteam/posts/09-02-16/transpose-or-just-rows-as-columns.aspx